# Can I access individual pixels on my 16x2 LCD display

Tags: lcd, library

I have a generic 16x2 LCD display connected to my Arduino.  I can use the standard LCD library to display characters, but are there way to turn on and of individual pixels?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to define custom characters for “generic 16x2 LCD displays” [ie, displays based on HD44780 or equivalent controllers], but only up to eight such characters at the same time.  See [LiquidCrystal.CreateChar](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalCreateChar) for details.  See page 2 and part of page 1 of the [Print degree symbol ° on LCD](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=19002.0) arduino.cc thread for create-character examples that don't use the library.  Page 1 of that thread also shows a table of all the characters built into typical HD44780 controllers, some of which may perhaps meet your needs.

For pixel-by-pixel LCD control, look at graphics LCDs, eg the [KS0108](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/GLCDks0108) or [LCD12864](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/LCD12864) and similar.

Comment: I am attempting to make a bar graph, so the 'CreateChar' function is great, but I wish I had more than 8 characters (20 would be ideal.)  Still, this might be the way to go.  \Unfortunately, none of the predefined characters works well for bar graphs.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need 20 different symbols for a simple bar graph. You can only have 5 different widths (horizontal bar), or 8 different height (vertical bar). Just do a [google image search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=lcd+bar+graph&hl=en&tbm=isch) to see some examples.